# import eclipse project with libries in to android studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I got eclipse project and I need to built that using Android Studio

My project folder is like this

-Project Foler
   - MyProjet
   - libs  (All libraries project are in this folder)

I used Android Studio import method. After I have imported the main project, I saw MyProject and libraries project are imported.

But I can't built the project, all libraries project reference are missing.

Could you please let me know what is the best way to import eclipse project into android studio.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

**Export from Eclipse**

```
    1.Update your Eclipse ADT Plugin (you must have version 22.0 or higher).

    2.In Eclipse, select File > Export.

    3.In the window that appears, open Android and select Generate Gradle build files.

    4.Select the projects you want to export for Android Studio and click Finish.

Your selected projects remain in the same location but now contain a build.gradle file and are ready for Android Studio.
```

**Import into Android Studio**

```
1.In Android Studio, select File > Import Project.

2.Locate a project you exported from Eclipse, select the project's root directory and click OK.

3.Select Create project from existing sources and click Next.

4.Follow the walk-through to complete the import process.
```

[Migrating to Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html)

Comment: Thanks Jignesh. I will setup eclipse. I don't have it now and will update you later.